# How to authenticate Laravel app user using a database user?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, mariadb

I want to use MariaDB (mysql) users to authenticate in a Laravel app. So instead of having a `users` table and a single database user for the whole application I want each login to be a separate database user and have permissions managed by the database. 
This will be an internal app used by no more than 10 users.

Do I need to create a custom user provider in Laravel? What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: You can create a custom middleware that will not use the default `Auth`

Comment: Have you thought about using a multi-role authentication? Just a thought, did not quite get your question.

Comment: I think the easiest solution would indeed be to create a custom UserProvider. This way you will be able to use all Laravel authentication functions.

Comment: @NicoBleiler I want to use database users to authenticate in web app. So let's say I've got user1. On the login page I enter: user1, password1 and then Laravel tries to connect to mysql database at localhost, user: user1, pass: password1 . If it succeeds I'm logged in and Laravel is using those credentials to read and write the database. If it doesn't succeed I present a "login failed" message.

Comment: @Radosław Gers Why do you want every user on a different Database, i do not think this is easily achieved and i do not see the point.

Comment: @NicoBleiler I don't want every user on a different database. They will all use the same database but will login as different database users with different permissions.
Database administrators in my company would like to manage user permissions through SQL.
Furthermore, using database triggers and functions I can easily implement modification history etc.